# Java read excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read this file I created as sample made up from 4 columns and 1 row. 
The code below was taken to test the API i am using i.e. Apache POI..

```
package testjavaexcel;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
/**
 *

 */
public class TestJavaExcel {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("poi-test.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");
            HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
            HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((short) 0);
            String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
            HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((short) 1);
            String b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();
            HSSFCell cellC1 = row1.getCell((short) 2);
            boolean c1Val = cellC1.getBooleanCellValue();
            HSSFCell cellD1 = row1.getCell((short) 3);
            Date d1Val = cellD1.getDateCellValue();

            System.out.println("A1: " + a1Val);
            System.out.println("B1: " + b1Val);
            System.out.println("C1: " + c1Val);
            System.out.println("D1: " + d1Val);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error coming from line "**HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);**" output is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   testjavaexcel.TestJavaExcel.main(TestJavaExcel.java:28) Java Result: 1

Not sure why this is happening...it seems like straight forward.note that the .getCell() methods invoked are all striked indicating deprecated methods but not sure how can I replace them given the API.

Thanks,

UPDATE: I figured out that the new method if getCell takes int instead of older version using short type. that fixed the deprecated warning. The rest remains unsolved. Also i am using ***poi version 3.8***

Comment: from your code, line 28 is `String b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();`

Comment: yeh that's why i added the line 28 on my code here as HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0); because there are more comments before class and after code that are added by netbeans. So line 28 here not same as there, hence the inclusion of error line

Comment: so in your excel book you have a sheet with the name "POI Worksheet" (exact name)?

Comment: oh damn thats the error! I made sure the file name is correct but not the sheet! I hate excel! thanks @LuiggiMendoza for pointing out the problem. Thanks. You might want to post this as answer so it be marked.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am making it more dynamic now...any idea how to get worksheet title automatically? because I am passing file path from JFileChooser but then I need to also specify sheet title.

Comment: You should make another question for this. Try not to merge 2 or more questions in 1 post. Plus, I guess the solution can be using a combination of `HSSFWorkbook#getNumberOfSheets` and `HSSFWorkbook#getSheetName`, both explained [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your excel book must have a sheet with the name "POI Worksheet" (exact name).